# Run unit test project on VS changes the Application information

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm trying to run a unit test on Visual Studio c# Form Solution, which uses another project, let's call this project A. 
Project A extracts data from the windows registry based on the Application.CompanyName, Which I've specified in the project Assembly Information. 
While running project A I get the company name I've specified in the project A assembly Information.
But when I run the unit test I get, "Microsoft Corporation", regardless of the company name I've specified in the unit test project.

I'm not sure why that happens and how to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running your application, which resides in Project A, you are running the executable that was built with your application info, and therefore is named according to your specification.

However when you perform a unit test, the application that is running is not your application, but the unit test runner, which looks like it's MSTest for you as it's outputting Microsoft.

Consider what you are actually trying to achieve here.  Perhaps break out the thing that provides runtime application info in to a mockable class, and just check that the value returned by your mocked item within the unit test is picked up and used how you would expect it to be used.

As a general unit testing tip, anything that interacts with the underlying OS (application info, file system, date/time, etc) is best being mocked as this is volatile information, and also not worth testing as the OS developers should have done that for you already.

Comment: Thank! I've read about mockable and now understand your point and tips.